# Fail to combine minus sign and character class shortcut in a character class in Bash regex test

Tags: regex, string, bash

It seems that Bash regex text cannot capture when `minus sign` and `character class shortcut` is matched in a `character class`. Could you help to comment about why ?

```
$ str='ab-cd.de'
$ echo $str | grep -P '[\w\-]+\.de' 
ab-cd.de
$ BashRegex='([\w\-]+)\.de'
$ if [[ ! $str =~ $BashRegex ]] ; then echo "Failed..."; fi
Failed...
$ BashRegex='[\w\-]+\.de'                                   
$ if [[ ! $str =~ $BashRegex ]] ; then echo "Failed..."; fi
Failed...
```

Thank you very much for your time !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash, the `\w` character class isn't supported. Instead, use this:

```
BashRegex='([-[:alnum:]_]+)\.de'
```

If you put the `-` at the start of the group, it cannot be interpreted as part of a range so it's not necessary to escape it. `[[:alnum:]]` contains all alphanumeric characters, so the only character missing is `_`.

A common idiom in Bash is to use `&&` or `||` for simple tests such as this:

```
[[ $str =~ $BashRegex ]] || echo "Failed..."
```

if the test fails, the message is printed.